# Storing Shell Output

Tags: java, linux, string, shell, buffer

I am trying to read the output of a shell command into a string buffer, the reading and adding the values is ok except for the fact that the added values are every second line in the shell output.
for example, I have 10 rows od shell output and this code only stores the 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, row .
Can anyone point out why i am not able to catch every row with this code ???
any suggestion or idea is welcomed :)

```
import java.io.*;

public class Linux {

    public static void main(String args[]) {


        try {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();

    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo");
    BufferedReader input =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while (input.readLine() != null) {
        //System.out.println(line);
    s.append(input.readLine() + "\n");

    }
    System.out.println(s.toString());



} catch (Exception err) {
    err.printStackTrace();
}    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code that I typically use with BufferedReader in situations like this:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat /proc/cpuinfo");
BufferedReader input =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
//Here we first read the next line into the variable
//line and then check for the EOF condition, which
//is the return value of null
while((line = input.readLine()) != null){
    s.append(line);
    s.append('\n');
}
```

On an semi-related note, when your code does not need to be thread safe it is better to use StringBuilder instead of StringBuffer as StringBuffer is synchronized.

Answer (score 3):

Each time you call `input.readLine()` you're reading a new line.  You're not doing anything with the one that you read inside the `while()` statement, you're just letting it fall on the floor.  You'll need to temporarily store its value and process it within the body of the loop.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your reply.

I tried with this also 

while (s.append(input.readLine()) != null) {
     
        //System.out.println(line);
 s.append(input.readLine() + "\n");

    }

But the code gets stucked, can you paste me an example ??